# Decompile source .deb package to post it on launchpad

Tags: deb, launchpad

I want to upload .deb package from [this solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/971876) to my launchpad repository, so that I could automate the process of installing specific packages for my laptop. A brief insight into the package contents showed that there are driver sources and installation script inside.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  This question seems to be very very vague.  You can also automate the installation of packages without having every package in a PPA, have you looked into that?

Comment: The question is in the title.

Comment: That's insufficient, your question is vague, even what's in the title.  Answer me this, what ***EXACTLY*** are you trying to accomplish?  And why?

Comment: "I want to upload .deb package from this (link is provided) solution to my launchpad repository, so that I could automate the process of installing specific packages for my laptop." - If you think this is vague, tell me at least one way to do this.

Comment: Ok, here is another interpretation: I have a .dep package from that solution. It is not binary, so obviously it should be uploadable to launchpad. I don't know how to upload without .dsc or .changes files.

Comment: How did you download the package?  A .deb is the compiled binary package.  A source package has no .deb files.

Comment: So you want your own PPA with those drivers in it? The bug you linked to says that the bug was fixed in ubuntu 13.10 - why not just use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite containing source code, any ".deb" qualifies as a "binary" package (making it less obvious that it can be uploaded as-is to launchpad).

By "decompile" I think you mean obtaining the files needed to produce the source packages (.dsc and .changes mainly) to upload to your PPA, so the package builds on the PPA.

You can't directly do this as the debian/control file included in the .deb contains only information pertaining the binary package, not the source package (the `Source` section was removed when building the binary). If you know enough about debian packaging, you could recreate the source section and test locally before uploading to your PPA.

However, if your systems are able to reach the PPA, there's no reason why they couldn't simply download and install the provided .deb file as-is, which is what I would suggest you do, assuming you're unable to just upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 as others have mentioned.